# object reference not set to an instance of an object C#

Tags: c#, database, exception

I'm trying to write a web application with some database interaction in C#.NET.  I'm getting an odd exception that I can't figure out where it's coming from.  I found the method that it is coming from and the code is as follows:

```
protected void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=myname-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dbNames;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Names WHERE FirstName=@FirstName AND LastName=@LastName", conn);
            char[] delims = new char[1];
            delims[0] = ' ';

            string[] names = cblNames.SelectedItem.Text.Split(delims);
            string fname = names[0];
            string lname = names[1];
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", fname));
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", lname));
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            cblNames.ClearSelection();
            LoadTable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Delete Table: "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm sure it gives you the line of code in which it happens... what is the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: please run app in debug mode and post your stack trace

Comment: I'm a little new to using visual studio.  Where would it tell me?  I have the exception just writing to the page.

Comment: @m.webster It is another part of the exception...Exception.StackTrace

Comment: Replace the `Message` with `ToString()` when you're placing the error in the response: `Response.Write("Delete Table: "+ex.ToString());`... that will print the entire exception including the stack trace. It's also good to learn how to use the debugger right about now.

Comment: What do you expect delims[1] to be in that code? You're passing that character to the split function without assigning anything to it.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  this is the entire exception:

Delete Table: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at WebDatabase.WebForm1.cmdDelete_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\myusername\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WebDatabase\WebDatabase\WebForm1.aspx.cs:line 56

Comment: @m.webster and what's on line 56?

Comment: so is it saying that cblNames.SelectedItem is null, or that the Split function just isn't returning anything?  I make sure to select something every time.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn where is he referencing `delims[1]`? I only saw `delims[0]` and that's being set to a space `delims[0] = ' ';` If the OP did try to reference `delims[1]` then that would give an out of range exception, not a object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: ok, it's telling me that the SelectedItem is null, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense...

Comment: @m.webster if `SelectedItem` is `null`, then you'll have to track down how it's being set. That will lead you to the source of your error. Whatever is supposed to set `SelectedItem` is not doing it properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I was having was that I wasn't getting the value on postback because I was leaving this little peace of code out of the page_load function:

```
If Not IsPostBack()
```

It was an elementary lapse in knowledge.  I have been developing in .NET since this question and I realize how horribly simple it is to make mistakes in a new language.  Thank you everyone for dealing with the past noob me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at the line of code that the error is being thrown at and/or simply debug the application. Otherwise, I can only make guesses as to where this could be occurring:

```
conn.Open(); //conn could be null (if your connection string is bad it would post back a null connection I believe
cblNames.SelectedItem.Text //cblNames could be null (doubtful), but SelectedItem definitely could
LoadTable(); could be throwing it up also
```

Without more debug information, that is the best answer you are probably going to get.

Answer (score 0):

> so is it saying that cblNames.SelectedItem is null, or that the Split function just isn't returning anything?

Well, it's either one or the other and only you have access to the code, so set a break point at that line and when you hit the break point check if `SelectedItem` is `null` or if the `Text` is `null`. To be exact, we can eliminate the second "option" since `Split` always returns something, even if it's just an empty array, it still doesn't return `null`.

### Update

Per your comments, it seems that `SelectedItem` is not being set, so you must track down what is supposed to set `SelectedItem` and verify that it's doing it correctly.

Comment: I appreciate you spending your time helping me.

So what I have figured out so far is that SelectedItem isn't being set.  It is supposed to be set when a user checks one of the options in a checkbox list.  Now, when a user checks one of the options, it looks like the table just resets.  Is this because I have autopost set to true?

Comment: The way I understand it (and I could be wrong because I have only been coding with C# and visual studio for a couple days) is that when someone checks one of the checkboxes that is populated into the combobox list, that value "gets selected."  when the delete button is clicked the combo box that is checked should then be the "SelectedItem"  but that is apparently not happening for some reason.  Any ideas?

Comment: @m.webster I'm not really sure... auto-post could be a problem, but I'm not familiar with the details of the various table libraries so I can't help much there.

Comment: I set autopost to true and it clears the selected checkbox before you can even click on the delete button.  it I set it to false it's like the value isn't actually saved.  This is just annoying now. lol.

Comment: @m.webster yah, I'm sorry... I'm just not familiar with how that works. However, I hope that my answer has pointed you in the right direction and even if you can't really solve the problem by yourself, then at least it will be easier for somebody else to help you.

Comment: I think that there has to be some kind of issue between the combobox list and the event handler for the button.  I tried changing it to a radio button list but it's the same issue.  I really don't understand why the selected index is not being set.  Thank you so much for the help though.  You got me farther than I expected to tonight.

Comment: BTW, are you doing something similar to [this code example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Additemstocombobox.htm)? Are you using Win Forms?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, `cblNames` can only be throwing exception. Check stacktrace for specific line of code.
On the other note, it's not recommended to catch the base exception as `catch (Exception ex)`. Always case specific exceptions instead e.g. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` or `System.InvalidOperationException`. For more details check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).